# How to instantiate a Form while the main form is still responsive

Tags: c#, winforms

I use .Net Framework 4.0 and C#. I want to dynamically instantiate a form in my code while the main form remains responsive. Is creating a new thread and call `Application.Run(newForm)` the only way of doing it? It just looks like a bit of a mess for such a simple thing. I thought it should be so common that the framework should have some kind of built-in functionality for this.

Comment: How are you showing the `Form`, with `ShowDialog()` or `Show()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need another thread to create a new form, and don't call `Application.Run` a second time. As long as you don't do anything that blocks the UI (and you never should), both forms will run just fine.

```
MyForm form = new MyForm();
form.Show();
```

If you call `ShowDialog` instead of `Show` from your first form, your first form will be blocked.